# Подгрузка стилей из другого файла и применение их к блоку

Tags: html, css

У меня есть разметка на пример вот такая

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page<title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>This is first page</p>

       <div class="preview-page">
         //содержимое страницы которую я хочу просмотреть
         <div class="header"><span>Header</span></div>
         <p>This is second page</p>
         <style>
         </style>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

У меня есть некая html страница с стилями для неё. Я хочу подгрузить содержимое html файла в div.preview-page и загрузить его стили в таг style. Если я так делаю то всё очень плохо.

вот пример стилей в файле который я подгружаю в div.preview-page

```
body{
   font-size:14px;
   background:green;
}
div.header{color:white;}
```

а это стили подключаемые к главной странице(верхней)

```
body{
   font-size:12px;
   background:red;
   color:blue;
}
div.header{width:100%;height:100px;backgound:black;}
```

Как мы видим стили конфликтуют,да если ещё на странице будет куча элиментов то они будут наследовать стили от главной страницы, получается куча всякой всячины, которая неправильно отображает страницу.

Решением может быть только в том, чтобы использовать только не неуникальные селекторы, отказаться от body,h1,span, но стили которые будут определены в конце(в теге style) перезаписывают стили всего, даже главной страницы. Как мне сделать правильно и изолировать стили? Я не хочу использовать iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lpgenerator.ru](http://lpgenerator.ru) использует `iframe` чтобы загрузить целую страницу сохраняя её контекст. Чтобы загрузить страницу или её часть не смешивая клоны селекторов, можно применить костыль, увидев который вы поймёте, что лучше использовать `iframe`, или менять модель и/или представление.

*Код не тестировался и был написан на скорую руку в качестве способа решения нетривиальной задачи, применять его крайне не целесообразно:*

```
var noframeContainer=$('insert-noframe-container');
/*загрузка->модификация->вставка страницы в контейнер*/
$.ajax({
    cache:false,
    type:/*или GET*/'POST',
    dataType:'html',
    beforeSend:function(){/*действия в начале загрузки*/},
    success:function(data){
        /*пришедшие данные*/
        var data=$(data)
           ,dataBody=data.find('body');
        /*EACH по стилям вставленным в тело документа (без src)*/
        data.find('style:not([src])').each(function(i){
            this.html(/*ВНИМАНИЕ. здесь вы должны каждому стилю приписать контекст, например, 
                был .element{display:block} 
               стал .insert-noframe-container .element{display:block} 
               сделать это нужно через регулярное выражение */)
            /*готовую таблицу стилей нужно переместить в начало body подгружаемой страницы*/
            .prependTo(dataBody);
        });
        /*тоже самое нужно проделать со стилями подгружаемыми извне (опять ajax, хотя есть и другой способ)*/
        data.find('style[src]').each(function(i){
            /*...*/
        })/*удалить (останутся только <style>...</style> внутри body)*/.remove();
        /*/EACH/*/
        /*теперь изменённые данные, только те что входитят в <body>...</body> (если нужно наследование от html body, то их прийдётся имитировать), нужно вставить в контейнер*/
        noframeContainer.html(dataBody);
    },
    data:senData,
    url:'http://localhost'});
/*теперь стили подгруженной страницы не будут влиять на стили родительской страницы, но не наоборот. Чтобы стили родительсой страницы не затрагивали стили дочерней, необходимо применить :not(.insert-noframe-container)*/
```

Также стоит помнить о javascript конфликтах.

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 0):

Стили нельзя изолировать. Частично можно обойти созданием неймспейса для классов, вроде container1_block и container2_block. Но это по сути разные классы и все. И уж никак вы не сможете изолировать селекторы по названию тегов, вроде body {...}, h1 {...}.

Единственный правильный способ изоляции - это iframe. Ваше нежелание им пользоваться просто смешно. Это все равно что сказать, я хочу построить дом, но принципиально не буду пользоваться для этого руками.

Comment: Посмотрите на вот этот сайт http://lpgenerator.ru/, я не вник в их тему

Comment: @WebWorkDeveloper и причем тут этот сайт?

Comment: У них нету frame и при этом они рагружают различные html файлы

Comment: Подгружать html файлы ничто не помешает и так, и стили можно подгружать. Только вот это нельзя изолировать.